# internal hard disk not found to resolve this issue try to reseat the drive

Tags: hard-drive

'internal hard disk not found to resolve this issue try to reseat the drive. No bootable devices--strike F1 to retry boot. F2 enter setup Menu F5 enter PSA.'

The full message is shown above.

When I pushed the F2 I saw the Fixed HDD in the Main Menu of the Setup screen.

I removed the HDD and reseated it an it was the same error upon bootup.

I wanted to get this new HDD in and install Windows 7 on it.

Laptop is Dell Inspiron 5423 14z.